# Auth0 - Sendgrid not sending Email but working on test email

Tags: email, sendgrid, auth0

I have just begun working with an account that had been set up by someone else using Auth0 and Sendgrid to handle email verification.

Ever since the 11th of December, the whole thing just stopped sending emails out of the blue. We thought it had to do with payment plan but even after the upgrade it didn't change anything.

But here's the weird part: When we send a test email the whole thing works perfectly, but when we try to re-send authentication email it doesn't.

Does anyone have any clue as to what might be going on? We've checked settings and price plan and neither are any different to other accounts with the same set-up, yet it hasn't been working since the 11th.

Comment: I am having the same problem now, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I work with the Auth0 Community team. Are you seeing anything in the logs about emails failing to send? Are verification emails turned on for your tenant? We also have a step by step setup doc for setting up Send Grid which you could use for confirming your current setup which I've shared below. I hope this helps you in the path forward.

https://auth0.com/docs/email/providers#configure-sendgrid

Comment: I have this issue now.  Test emails work both from configuring "Email Templates" and from "Email Provider", but when I try to login via the app, Auth0 logs: ```"details": {
  "email_type": "verification_code",
  "to": "<my_email>",
  "error": "The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit <sendgrid_documentation> to see the Sender Identity requirements"
}```. We are using Netlify to manage DNS and have completed sender and domain verification on SendGrid.